# How to capture change of Clarity Date Picker

Tags: datepicker, angular6, vmware-clarity

I am using the double-binding of the clrDate, which allows me to load a Javascript Date object.  However, I need to trigger an event every time the user changes the date, either types in a new one or uses the calendar.

I've tried (click), (change), (ngModelChange), (blur) - but for some reason none of them seem to trigger.

```
<label for="modelDate" class="clr-control-label" >Model Date:</label>     
<input clrDate type="date" [(clrDate)]="selectedModelDate" (ngModelChange)="loadModel(false)" >
```

How should I capture the change within the Date Picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

## **2-way Binding**

In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-52882650-date-2-way-binding), notice that before the date picker is interaced with, if you click the button then the value of `date1` is undefined. After you select a date and click the button it has the value set in the date picker. This is typical 2-way binding in Angular.

```
<section>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="logDate1()">
    Log Date Value for 2-way binding
  </button>
  <label for="date1" class="clr-control-label" > Date1:</label>     
  <input type="date" [(clrDate)]="date1" />
</section>
```

### **De-sugarized Syntax**

This might be what you are after. It's almost the same as the above example but we seperate or *de-sugarize* the 2-way binding so that it gets set with `[clrDate]=date2`. Notice that it fires an event `clrDateChange` that can be tied into with the `logChnage($event)`. That will get fired whenever the internal value of the date picker changes (e.g user selects a date) and you can do whatever you want with it's value in the `logChange` function. This is 2-way binding `de-sugarized`.

```
<section>
  <h4>De-sugarized syntax</h4>
  <label for="date2" class="clr-control-label" > Date1:</label>     
  <input type="date" [clrDate]="date2" (clrDateChange)="logChange($event)"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks hippeelee, I resolved the issue by adding (clrDateChange) as the event to capture.  The event wasn't listed within the Clarity documents.

Comment: (clrDateChange) is not part of the documentation because its part of how Angular handles two way bindings. Any two way binding `[()]` can be split into an individual input and output just like this, with the same name convention, by adding Change to the output name.